# Risks associated with compiling open source projects

Tags: opensource

After reading [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32889/is-it-safer-to-compile-open-source-code-vs-simply-running-the-binary) about if it's safer to download and compile the source for an open source project or download and run the installer, I thought of another possible vulnerability: is it conceivable a compiler could be designed to leave a back door (or other malware) inside a file it outputs? In other words could the compiler used to compile the source code be compromised? The only way such a thing could be caught would be to dissasemble a compiled executable and compare the code with the original. This would be very difficult.

Also you would need a preexisting compiler to compile an open source compiler. Is it even theoretically possible to have a system that is all open source software and the computer owner (or a group of trusted people) has reviewed the code for the programs used?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the compiler, as any other program that executes code on your computer, can be used to add malicious instructions in a program, before or also after compiling it ([e.g. ELF header and sections manipulation](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/hh/virus/unix-viruses.txt)).

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the chain of trust. Do you trust the source of the code author, have you or someone you trust reviewed the code, do you *trust the compiler*. It is indeed possible for a compiler to be distributed that inserts backdoors, malicious code, etc.

> Ken Thompson's Reflections on Trusting Trust, his Turing Award
>   acceptance speech in 1984, was the first major paper to describe
>   [black box backdoor issues, and points out that trust is relative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backdoor_%28computing%29#Reflections_on_Trusting_Trust).

It's also possible that your compiler may [not act as intended and could reduce the insecurity of the code](http://www.itworld.com/security/380406/how-your-compiler-may-be-compromising-application-security):

> Four researchers in MIT’s Computer Science and Artificial Intelligence
>   Laboratory, in a paper which is to be presented next week at the ACM
>   Symposium on Operating Systems Principles, looked at the problem of
>   optimization-unstable code, which is code that gets removed by a
>   compiler because it includes undefined behavior. Undefined behavior is
>   code which can behave unpredictably, such as dividing by zero, null
>   pointer dereferencing and buffer overflows. Unlike other code,
>   compiler writers are free to deal with undefined behavior however they
>   wish. In some cases, they choose to eliminate it completely, which can
>   lead to vulnerabilities if the code in question contains security
>   checks.